# Plot Julia - Fractal

Tags: fractals

I want to obtain the following figure, but I did not manage to obtain it, any suggestion?

[image: Fig. 1]
[image: Fig. 2]

```
julia[c_, z_, m_] := 
  ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ 
    Nest[Flatten[(Map[w, #] /. k -> c), 1] &, {z}, m], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Prolog -> PointSize[250]];

julia[0.4 + 0.7 I, 2 + I, 15]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you please type your code so that those who wish to help you can copy and paste it?

Comment: From what I see your w and k are blue meaning they are undefined, this may be the source of your issues. But please edit your post with your code in a typed, copy and paste-able format, so that others may test and see what the problem is. You can use markdown code formatting to make it more clear that it is code as well.

Comment: you need to define your w that is, according to your code, a function of z with some constant k. I don’t think your numbers are right for `w[z_]:=z^2+k`, however.

Comment: @Halsey12: JuliaSetPlot[-1, ColorFunction -> None]

Answer (score 4):

Just to make the result a bit closer to the image you showed:

```
JuliaSetPlot[-1, ColorFunction -> None,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
  PlotStyle->Black,ImageSize -> Large, 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, {-0.75, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75}},  
  BaseStyle -> 14]
```

(Added `PlotStyle -> Black` to make result like original question's image.)

[image: Julia plot with axes and ticks]

Comment: Not sure why this would get a downvote, great answer! I forgot about this function! +1

Comment: @murray, add the `PlotStyle->Black` option to set the curve to black.

Comment: @creidhne: Of course! I thought I had tried that but got some unexpected result; I was quite wrong.